# Implanting mouse simulation need visual feed back that mouse is clicked

Tags: c#-3.0

Implanting mouse simulation application using c# and winApi to control other windows application , need to blink the cursor when I simulates Mouse click event. so that I will get a visual feed back that mouse is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame() or ControlPaint.DrawReversibleLine() to draw a quick series of disappearing concentric shapes to give feedback.  When you draw the exact same frame/line twice with these methods they erase themselves and restore whatever was there before.